# Save and reload OCR result of Abbyy FineReader

Tags: ocr, abbyy, finereader, finereader12-sdk

Assume I have OCR-ed multiple PDFs in Abbyy FindeReader. Is it possible to reload the OCR results in Abbyy FineReader at a later time in order to correct OCR errors?

My idea is that I want to split executing the OCR and (at a later time) correcting the OCR results

Comment: is this for Python sdk or something else?

Comment: The idea is that the OCR results of multiple PDFs are generated by Abbyy Finereader, e.g. by means of batch processing, and the question is wether those results can be reloaded in Abbyy Finereader later.

Comment: Based on your question, are you sure you are using the FineReader Engine SDK ? Anyway, based on your use case, you either need FlexiCapture or the desktop version of FineReader (not the SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use "File" - "Save" command to save the recognition results together will all the intermediate data.